# Getting all files from root folder of a Source Safe database creates folders only. No files present

Tags: visual-sourcesafe

I did a Get Latest from the root folder ($) of a Source Safe database and all I got is all the folders hierarchy. There were no files anywhere. But if I do a Get Latest on each folder (project), I do the files for that folder hiearachy.

Why does this happen? Is this a permissions issue?

Comment: Do you check the 'recursive' option?

Comment: Yes. All the folders are created so this is proof recursive is on?

Comment: Any luck, with this problem. I am facing the same issue, only folders are created but not files .

Answer (score 0):

I have the same question... It plays when checking out a toplevel project ($/Projects) 
Below that is ok ($/Project/Demo1) works

-- EDIT: Solved

With patience the files started appearing after all. I know for sure that it had finished before, but that was on a copy of SSEXP started from withing visual studio 2008. Perhaps some memory restriction plays a role (makes it fail for large volumes of trees with many files, without displaying a proper error message?).

Anyhow, redoing the get from a SSEXP started with Visual Studio closed (and applying *LOTS* of patience) worked for me in the end